# Simple combinatorics problem: In how many ways can $7$ couples be seated if each man must sit between two women?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Simple combinatorics problem , we have 7 couples that want to be seated around a table , in how many ways can we do that given that each man has to sit between 2 women.

---

The answer in the book is "first we seat a woman anywhere on the table (doesn't matter where since its circular). then the other 6 women we can sit in $6!$ ways , between the women we can seat the men in $7!$ ways thus we get $7! \cdot 6!$ (no difference if we first seat a woman or man)" (hopefully the translation is correct)

If we seat a woman first then we have $6$ left , but doesn't that leave us with $5!$ ways around a table and not $6!$? and to seat the men don't we need $6!$ and not $7!$?

If it doesn't matter if a man or woman are seated first, don't we have to multiply by $2$?

I tried solving it differently but could not figure out how to continue, I tried looking at the set (woman,man,woman) as a single unit then we have 2 ways of sorting this set because we can change the place of the women only but I could not continue from here as I don't know what to do with the $11$ units left (I think 11+1(the unit that contains those three).

Any tips and help will be appreciated.

Comment: When we put one woman, we got 6 places which tied to the first woman. That mean we can actually enumerate and freeze the number for these 6 places which leads us to 6! The mens' places are also tied to the woman, so we can freeze the numbers for men and get 7!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your two doubts

**(1)** It is in a *straight line* seating with $n$ people seated that the gaps between seated people will be $(n-1)$ Draw a circle and satisfy yourself that in circular seating, the gaps will be $n$

**(2)** You won't need to multiply by $2$ because suppose you had seated the woman at $12$ o'clock position, if you ask everyone to move one seat clockwise, say, it will be the same arrangement, but with the man at the $12$o'clock position